# Custom analyzer for Elasticsearch

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I am trying to use [Sudachi](https://github.com/WorksApplications/elasticsearch-sudachi) plugin in my Elasticsearch using python. I have verified that the plugin has bee installed and it is working fine using JSON directly, and the paths exist. However, I am not able to integrate it into my python code. I suspect I have the tokenizer and/or analyzer wrong, but the documentation is not very clear to me. Any help in overcoming the error is welcome, Thanks!

```py
    from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
    from elasticsearch_dsl.connections import connections
    from elasticsearch_dsl import analyzer, tokenizer, Document, Text

    INDEX_NAME = 'my_text_index'

    class DocumentObject(Document):
        body = Text(analyzer='sudachi_analyzer')
        class Index:
            name = INDEX_NAME


    host = 'localhost'
    port = 9200
    connection = connections.create_connection(hosts=[{'host':host,'port':port}])
    es = Elasticsearch(hosts=[{'host':host,'port':port}]) 
    try:
        es.indices.close(index=INDEX_NAME)
    except:
        pass   

    sudachi_tokenizer = tokenizer(
            "sudachi_tokenizer",
            type="sudachi_tokenizer",
            mode="normal",
            discard_punctuation="true",
            resources_path="/Users/.../sudachi",
            settings_path="/Users/.../sudachi/sudachi.json"
        )
    sudachi_analyzer = analyzer(
        "sudachi_analyzer",
        tokenizer=sudachi_tokenizer,
        filter=[
                "sudachi_part_of_speech",
                "sudachi_ja_stop",
                "sudachi_normalizedform"
            ],
        type="custom",
        char_filter= []
        )

    DocumentObject.init()
```

This is the error I get

```
elasticsearch.exceptions.RequestError: RequestError(400, 'mapper_parsing_exception', 'analyzer [sudachi_analyzer] not found for field [body]')
```

For reference this the the JSON for the Sudachi analyzer which is working:

```
   "index": {
      "analysis": {
        "tokenizer": {
          "sudachi_tokenizer": {
            "type": "sudachi_tokenizer",
            "mode": "normal",
            "discard_punctuation": true,
            "resources_path": "/Users/.../sudachi",
            "settings_path": "/Users/.../sudachi/sudachi.json"
          }
        },
        "analyzer": {
          "sudachi_analyzer": {
            "tokenizer": "sudachi_tokenizer",
            "type": "custom",
            "char_filter": [],
            "filter": [
              "sudachi_part_of_speech",
              "sudachi_ja_stop",
              "sudachi_normalizedform"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Can you make sure to delete the index before running your code? If the index already exists, then the custom analyzer won't be created.

Comment: I do not have the index, trying to close it gives me an error. I updated the code to clarify.

Comment: You get an error when trying to close because the index doesn't exist?

Comment: Yes, this is the error I get
```elasticsearch.exceptions.NotFoundError: NotFoundError(404, 'index_not_found_exception', 'no such index [my_text_index]', my_text_index, index_or_alias)```

Comment: Ok that makes sense, the index doesn't exists, so you cannot close or delete it. Can you reorder your code a bit and create the custom analyzer before declaring your `DocumentObject` class?

Comment: It is the same error. I have updated the question with the custom analyzer JSON for reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like this, you need to reference your custom analyzer instance, not its name:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
from elasticsearch_dsl.connections import connections
from elasticsearch_dsl import analyzer, tokenizer, Document, Text

INDEX_NAME = 'my_text_index'

sudachi_tokenizer = tokenizer(
        "sudachi_tokenizer",
        type="sudachi_tokenizer",
        mode="normal",
        discard_punctuation="true",
        resources_path="/Users/.../sudachi",
        settings_path="/Users/.../sudachi/sudachi.json"
    )
sudachi_analyzer = analyzer(
    "sudachi_analyzer",
    tokenizer=sudachi_tokenizer,
    filter=[
            "sudachi_part_of_speech",
            "sudachi_ja_stop",
            "sudachi_normalizedform"
        ],
    type="custom",
    char_filter= []
    )

class DocumentObject(Document):
    body = Text(analyzer=sudachi_analyzer)    <---- remove the ticks, not a string, but the instance
    class Index:
        name = INDEX_NAME


host = 'localhost'
port = 9200
connection = connections.create_connection(hosts=[{'host':host,'port':port}])
es = Elasticsearch(hosts=[{'host':host,'port':port}]) 


DocumentObject.init()
```

Comment: I still get the same error even after reordering and removing the ticks.

Comment: Which error? notice I also removed the close index bit.

Comment: Sorry, not the same error: ```elasticsearch.exceptions.RequestError: RequestError(400, 'illegal_argument_exception', 'Unknown tokenizer type [sudachi_tokenizer] for [sudachi_tokenizer]')```

Comment: it's different now, it's the `sudachi_tokenizer` not the `sudachi_analyzer` anymore

Comment: Thanks for the help. Turns out that my installation was incomplete. Also, the `paths` should refer to the elasticsearch `config` directory, or can be omitted.

Comment: Cool, glad you figured it out.